# C++ names pipes, write unsigned int safely

Tags: c++, pipe, named-pipes

I am trying to pass numbers between processes in C++ using pipes. I am constrained in the write size I must use to I use unsigned int to get the maximum size for 4 bytes.

I want to implement error checking both read and write, for example if my listener process did not read all four (4) bytes or the writer did not write all 4 bytes at once, to read again until I write/read exactly 4 by moving the pointer in those already writen/read until I complete the size I want .

This is my code for char arrays (strings) that reads 'buffer_size' chunks of a 'content_size' string from the pipe and writes them to a file pointer 'fp':

```
while(size_read < content_size)
        {
            nread
            memset(chunk, '\0', buffer_size+1);
            if ((content_size-size_read)<buffer_size)   //  for the last read, try to read only until the 'content_size' byte, instead of buffer_size
            {
                nread=read(fd, chunk, (content_size-size_read));    
            }
            else    //  all the other times, read buffersize
            {
                nread=read(fd, chunk, buffer_size);
            }

            if(size_read+nread==content_size)
            {
                // fwrite(chunk,nread,1,fp);
                fwrite(chunk,strlen(chunk),1,fp);
                break;
            }
            size_read+=nread;
            if ((content_size-size_read)<buffer_size)   //  
            {
                while(nread<(content_size-size_read))
                {
                    nread+=read(fd, chunk+nread, (content_size-size_read)-nread);
                    // size_read+=nread;    //  edw 
                    if(size_read==content_size)
                    {
                        done=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                fwrite(chunk,strlen(chunk),1,fp);
                // size_read+=nread;
            }
            else
            {
                how_much_i_will_have_read_at_end= buffer_size-nread;
                while(nread<buffer_size)
                {
                    nread+=read(fd, chunk+nread, buffer_size-nread);
                    if(size_read==content_size)
                    {
                        done=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // fwrite(chunk,buffer_size,1,fp);
                fwrite(chunk,strlen(chunk),1,fp);
                size_read+=how_much_i_will_have_read_at_end;
            }
            if(done) break;
        }
```

How can I implement something like this with integers or numbers in general?

Comment: You should start by checking the return values of all invocations to fwrite() and fread()!

Comment: I don't think there's any need to "verify" that all have been sent or received. For normal pipes, the default is to be blocking. That is, if the pipe is full then `write` will block. And if the pipe is empty then `read` will block. Pipe are not like UDP sockets, which are unreliable and data could get lost. The only way for data to get lost in a pipe is if you have multiple readers without synchronization, or if the pipe is closed before all data have been read from it.

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo do you mean write and read? I only use fwrite in my code to write the chunk I read from the pipe to my file in fp.

Comment: The basic task of "read exactly N bytes from a pipe, retrying if needed", shouldn't take more than 5 or 6 lines, far less than the multiple pages of shown code. The actual call to `read()` should appear exactly once, in there, and not the many times shown here, for unclear reasons.

Comment: I agree with you that it could be less complicated, but commenting on the working code that I provided for example is not helping to answer the question. I don't mean to offend you, but this code is just to show the "read again until you read N" logic that I want to use with numbers now.

Comment: `memset(chunk, '\0', buffer_size+1);` the +1 looks suspicious

Comment: There seems to be a bug at `fwrite(chunk,strlen(chunk),1,fp);`. The target file has no way to know where the string ends. The `\0`  at the end of the string is chopped off, and neither is string size written at the beginning. The reader has no way to know how many bytes to read.